# Network connection stopping ros subscription

Tags: ros, ubuntu, network, ros-fuerte, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whilst running the tutorial:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot

I am trying to write a rosjava program that will subscribe to the robots laser data and then publish messages. When I run the program whilst not being connected to a network it runs as expected and prints out a message to show that it is working.

However when I run it whilst connected to a wireless network the program doesn't appear to be receiving any messages and throws the following exceptions:

```
INFO: Subscriber registered: Subscriber<Topic<TopicIdentifier</base_scan>, TopicDescription<sensor_msgs/LaserScan, 90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369>>>
25-Nov-2012 14:04:37 org.ros.internal.node.topic.UpdatePublisherRunnable run
SEVERE: org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: Connection exception: Laptop2012/67.198.168.6:36300
25-Nov-2012 14:04:37 org.ros.internal.node.topic.UpdatePublisherRunnable run
SEVERE: org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: Connection exception: Laptop2012/67.198.168.6:36300
25-Nov-2012 14:04:37 org.ros.internal.transport.ConnectionTrackingHandler exceptionCaught
SEVERE: Channel exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
25-Nov-2012 14:04:37 org.ros.internal.transport.ConnectionTrackingHandler exceptionCaught
SEVERE: Channel exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Does anyone know how or why this is happening relating to my network connection and if I can fix it.

I am running Fuerte on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx).

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49061/network-connection-stopping-ros-subscription/) by [heyfred](https://answers.ros.org/users/1930/heyfred/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also see a similar behavior. I *think* that ROS cannot find where the nodes are if there are multiple Domain Name Servers (DNS). In my set-up, I have one on the ROS network, and one from my company, which "appears" only when I connect to the WLAN.

One solution could be to hard-code your computer names and IPs in the /etc/hosts file, which can be annoying to maintain. But give it a try in your setup, who knows!

---

Originally posted by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) with karma: 867 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2013-01-01**:
That's possible. Please file a bug: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list